# Is there a faster way with do this?

Tags: python

So I'm doing a python project and I need to organize a list of values by dictionary. I would like to know if there's a faster way than just doing what I'm doing.

This is what I've done, is there a more efficient and easier way to do this?

```py
def catogorize_by_mortality(hurricanes):
  damage_scale = {0: 0, 1: 100, 2: 500, 3: 1000, 4: 1e4}
  hurricane_mortality_dict = {0:[], 1:[], 2:[], 3:[], 4:[], 5:[]}
  for hurricane in hurricanes:
    current_hurricane = hurricanes[hurricane]
    death_count = current_hurricane['Deaths']
    if death_count > damage_scale[0] and death_count < damage_scale[1]:
      hurricane_mortality_dict[0] += hurricane

    elif death_count > damage_scale[1] and death_count < damage_scale[2]:
      hurricane_mortality_dict[1] += hurricane

    elif death_count > damage_scale[2] and death_count < damage_scale[3]:
      hurricane_mortality_dict[2] += hurricane

    elif death_count > damage_scale[3] and death_count < damage_scale[4]:
      hurricane_mortality_dict[3] += hurricane

    elif death_count >= damage_scale[4]:
      hurricane_mortality_dict[4] += hurricane

    else:
      hurricane_mortality_dict[5] += hurricane

  return hurricane_mortality_dict

# example of the hurricanes dictionary when printed
{'Cuba I': {'Name': 'Cuba I', 'Month': 'October', 'Year': 1924, 'Max Sustained Wind': 165, 'Areas Affected': ['Central America', 'Mexico', 'Cuba', 'Florida', 'The Bahamas'], 'Deaths': 90}

# this is what it returns
deaths.')
{0: ['C', 'u', 'b', 'a'
```

What's supposed to happen is that it will return the hurricane's names categorized but instead it splits them up into characters what's happening?

Comment: can you provide an example of the `hurricanes` argument you're using, and an example of what your expected output is?

Comment: You are having all the values in iterable structures already, so why not use an approach with iteration?

Comment: each value in hurricane_mortality_dict is a list right, how can you try to add something to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hurricane_mortality_dict[i]` is defined as a list, near the top of the function:

```
hurricane_mortality_dict = {0:[], 1:[], 2:[], 3:[], 4:[], 5:[]}
```

So in your conditional, when you do `hurricane_mortality_dict[i] += hurricane`, you're trying to add a `string` and a `list`, which treats the string as a `list` of characters - hence your output.

All you need to do is change each:

```
hurricane_mortality_dict[i] += hurricane
```

to:

```
hurricane_mortality_dict[i].append(hurricane)
```

For your example input this then results in:

```
{0: ['Cuba I'], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: []}
```